# multibib - multiple authors in reference not displayed

Tags: bibtex, apacite, multibib

I am using the multibib package to generate two bibliographies. Everything works fine but if the reference has more than 5 authors my bibliography is displayed like this:

[image]

Unfortunately, the multibib package does not respond to options like [maxbibnames]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{booktabs}           % To thicken table lines
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\let\Tiny=\tiny
\usepackage{tikz}               % allows drawing figures
\usepackage{setspace}           % allows for \onehalfspacing and \doublespacing to set linespacing
\usepackage{color, soul}        %For \hl
\usepackage{colortbl}           % Defined more color names in tables
\newcommand{\scaling}{.2}
\newcommand{\scalingmid}{.5}



\input{\settingsdir/latex-headerVprop.tex}
\usepackage[pdfpagelabels=true,plainpages=false,pdftex,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}%plainpage and pdfpagelabels allows for correct figure links when using different page numberings
% bookmarksnumbered=false shuts off TOC numbers in TOC of PDF
% bookmarksopen=true opens TOC in Abobe Reader on the left


\onehalfspacing

\usepackage[nonumberlist, %switch of displaying page numbers 
acronym,      %creates List of Abbreviations
toc,          %triggers entry into table of content
section      %defines the level where the TOC entry appears
]{glossaries} % used to create list of symbols and abbreviations; one of the few packages to be defined after hyperref


\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{List of Symbols} 
\newglossary[glg]{gloss}{gli}{glout}{Glossary}


\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{0.8\textwidth}

\makeglossaries 
%\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{0.85}

\input{glossary.tex}

%%%Setting up multiple bib environment
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{M}{Online References}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewenvironment{APACrefURL}[1][]{}{}
\AtBeginEnvironment{APACrefURL}{\renewcommand{\url}[1]{}}
\renewcommand{\doiprefix}{doi:~\kern-1pt}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small,labelfont=bf,singlelinecheck=off}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\begin{document}
 (my text)

\begin{singlespace}
    \setlength\bibitemsep{10pt} 
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{bibname}
\end{singlespace}

\end{document}
```

Does someone know how to modify the multibib package to display all athors?

Comment: `maxbibnames` is a `biblatex` option. `multibib` is a BibTeX-based bibliography package (and thus completely incompatible with `biblatex`). In fact `multibib` does not influence the bibliography style at all. That is still controlled by the style you select in `\bibliographystyle`. `apacite` (which is what you select) follows the APA guidelines which require the output you see. You'd have to modify the `.bst` file to change this behaviour, but that is a bit more painful than just setting an option.

Comment: I should add that I don't think it is advisable to use `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` without `\usepackage{apacite}`.